# Installing software without Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line, software-center, tar

I have a file downloaded from the Internet.

To be specific I downloaded **Code::Blocks** from its official [site](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads). 
The file name is **`codeblocks.tar.bz2`**.

If I don't have Internet connection and also Ubuntu Software Center is not working, how do I install the software?

I think I will have to use terminal but I am not used to with terminal. So please make it as simple as possible.

Comment: A bit more information is needed, does the `tar.bz2` contain the source code, or a deb file? which application is it?

Comment: To be specific I downloaded codeblocks from the official codeblocks site. The file name is codeblocks.tar.bz2.

Comment: Can u provide the download link. I can't seem to find the file for download!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [codeblocks download section](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads) there are three options available.

- Binaries
- Source
- SVN

### Binaries

If you downloaded the package from Binaries section then your file will be something like this "codeblocks-10.05-1-debian-i386.tar.bz2"

- untar the package file

  `lbzip2 -d codeblocks-10.05-1-debian-i386.tar.bz2`
  `tar xvf codeblocks-10.05-1-debian-i386.tar`

  or

  `tar xvjf codeblocks-10.05-1-debian-i386.tar.bz2`

  Then use `dpkg -i package_name.deb` or `dpkg -i *.deb` to install the package. **Make sure you run the deb in proper order to avoid dependencies**.

### Source

Download the file, sample: codeblocks-10.05-1debian-src.tar.bz2 and untar it the same way how it is done for binaries.

```
./configure 
make
make install
```

make sure you have installed `build-essential` before trying the above steps.

### SVN

You need install SVN package before proceeding the following steps.

Code base is at repository: http://svn.berlios.de/svnroot/repos/codeblocks/trunk

Checkout the code using command `svn checkout http://svn.berlios.de/svnroot/repos/codeblocks/trunk`. (This step needs internet connection.)

Read the README & README.debian for instructions on how to install without internet-access

Comment: For binaries, you could have add the GUI way. Using nautilus, right-click on the .tar.bz2 and **Extract here**. Then double-click on the .deb.

Comment: @user55822 feel free to edit the answer and help the OP. Thanks :)

Comment: I think i installed Code::Blocks following the procedure you gave for binaries because I can see codeblocks in application group when I search for it in dash. But when i click on it, codeblocks doesn't open, is there anything I have to do more.

Comment: Can you try opening the same in terminal and post the error message. Thanks

Comment: I didn't try typing `codeblocks` in terminal before, but when I did it now; **Code::Blocks** opened and worked fine.

Comment: But still **Code::Blocks** doesn't open when I click on its icon which i've locked in my launcher.

Comment: can you paste the .desktop file contents?

Comment: where can I find this file?

Comment: Can you join this chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6422/room-for-devav2-and-prakash-gautam

Answer (score 1):

There's a step-by-step tutorial on the Codeblocks wiki for installing it on Ubuntu: [Installing Code::Blocks nightly build on Ubuntu](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Code%3a%3aBlocks_nightly_build_on_Ubuntu)

If you aren't required to use Codeblocks, then perhaps you should try a more easily-installed C++ editor, such as Geany, which you can find in the Software Center or by typing (in the terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

Geany is pretty nice as editors go. If you don't have Internet access, make sure to follow the steps to add the Ubuntu installation DVD/CD as a package source: [Installing software packages without an Internet connection](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/add-applications/C/offline.html)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably downloaded a source tarball. Usually what that means is that you have to install libraries/utilities that are required to the compilation of your software and then configure, build and install the compiled program.

There's no single way to do that, usually when you unpack your tarball, there's either a README* or INSTALL* file that describes what needs to be done to install it. It's fairly common to just:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/myapp
make
make install
```

There's a drawback to this method - you'll end up with files installed completely outside of your package management system that your PMS has no idea about and cannot manage. It's usually fine for temporary testing and if you know what you're doing and keep files installed in such a way in a separate directory.

You said you're not used to working in the terminal - unfortunately working in the terminal is the least complicated part of compiling programs from scratch.

You might want to find your application among packages already available to Ubuntu and download the Ubuntu distribution on the DVD and then use apt-cdrom to add it as a source of available packages.

PS. if what you've downloaded is an already built application, you can view the contents using:

```
tar tjf program.tar.bz2
```

and

```
tar xjf program.tar.bz2
```

but you have to be sure that you know what you're running. I'd look for the way to run your application in one of the files within that archive.